# Beamer - ! File ended while scanning use of \next

Tags: beamer, errors

I ran into an issue with the following code

```
\begin{document}


    \begin{frame}[fragile] % Start of frame

        \begin{columns}[t]

            \begin{column}{.02\textwidth}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

            \begin{column}{.465\textwidth} % The first column


                \begin{block}

                    \begin{minted}{c}
                        int main() {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    \end{minted}

                \end{block}
            \end{column}

        \end{columns}
    \end{frame} % End of frame
\end{document}
```

With the following error

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
            \par
```

I'm putting my solution here because I wasted hours trying to figure out what went wrong with such a cryptic error message

Comment: can you make your example compilable by including `\documentclass` and relevant `\usepackage`s? It seems strange that indenting `\end{frame}` and putting comments after it would cause problems...

Comment: @KevinC it's not strange in `beamer` (one of the tags), due to the way the `fragile` option causes frames with verbatim material to be processed.

Comment: @glitchyme In case you are interested in a work around http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234789/36296

Comment: should be fixed with https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/0c387deb21263aff6bc4864618e3cb74dcf32357

Comment: I just spent hours trying to find the source of the error rendering a .Rnw file with `knitr` until I found this discussion, especially the answer of [glitchyme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/71434/glitchyme).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The fix was 2-part

- `\end{frame}` can NOT be indented
- `\end{frame}` cannot have any comments directly after it

Changing this line fixed the error.

Comment: So we can neither properly indent our code nor comment why the particular line is poorly indented :-).

Comment: Totally arbitrary "errors" like this is certainly the worst of Latex. You waste so much time looking for an invisible space, something you would never imagine could breaks the whole compilation up.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error message and the problem was a `[fragile]` in

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}
 ...
\end{frame}
```

that I use for frames that contain LaTeX Listings code. I put it there before actually using Listings in that frame.