# Indenting \end{frame} in fragile slides

Tags: beamer

> This problem was fixed in [beamer v3.37](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/0c387deb21263aff6bc4864618e3cb74dcf32357), if you still experience this problem try to update to a recent version of beamer

Suddenly I am no longer able to indent `\end{frame}` for slides with the `fragile` option, e.g.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        test
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

does not work but gives the error `File ended while scanning use of \next.`

---

Comparing the logfiles to previous presentations showed different versions of the `beamer` package and taking a look at recent changes made I think I was able to pinpoint the responsible commit to [2e946022](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/cbae16774fc9b0293893f128c2be72f42e946022) where

```
\beamer@makeinnocent\^^I % Allow tab chars
```

was added to the package.

As I understand this allows the usage of tabs in `listings`. While this might be helpful for people who actually use tabs inside `listings` it breaks backwards compatibility with many of my presentations and, to be honest, I like the ability to indent code, because it make it easier to read for me.

---

**Question:**

Long story short: Can I somehow revert this locally? Preferably without hacking my local LaTeX distribution so that the fix will survive further updates?

Comment: Don't indent `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`. That's all. By the way, I see no purpose in indenting the whole document.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for your quick reply. I am aware that not indenting would solve the issue, but I hope someone will come up with another solution, so that I do not have to change all my old presentations

Comment: is your actual document indented with tabs (the code above indents with space)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I use tabs, but I have the same problem if using spaces

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you pinpointed exactly what caused the change, this works (using tab for indent)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@verbatimreadframe{%
  \begingroup%
  \let\do\beamer@makeinnocent\dospecials%
  \count@=127%
  \@whilenum\count@<255 \do{%
    \advance\count@ by 1%
    \catcode\count@=11%
  }%
  \beamer@makeinnocent\^^L% and whatever other special cases
% \beamer@makeinnocent\^^I % Allow tab chars
  \endlinechar`\^^M \catcode`\^^M=12%
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\afterassignment\beamer@specialprocessframefirstline\let\beamer@temp=}{\beamer@processframefirstline}}%


\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        test
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You probably don't want to put that into your old presentations but if you put a copy of `beamerbaseverbatim.sty` into the same directory as your presentation and comment out the line you highlighted, indenting with tabs will work (although it's probably not a good idea going forward)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Both your suggestions work fine and especially simply putting a modified `beamerbaseverbatim.sty` in the old folders works great!