# Error when using [fragile] in beamer

Tags: beamer, verbatim

I've got a problem in beamer. When using the fragile option on a frame, the compilation does not work. 
For instance:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile]

      Hello World

  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

```
File ended while scanning use of \next
```

Do you know why ? 
I tried with miktex and Texlive, on windows and Mac.
 Many thanks for your help, 
Best,
 Nicolas

Comment: @egreg sort of is duplicate, but the reported error is different, so possibly? best to let it stand.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I run the other example, I get exactly the same error. Tried with TL from 2010 to 2015. I edited the question with the real error message.

Comment: @NicolasDebarsy In case you like indenting your code, have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234789/36296 for a workaround - I once had the same problem and it drove me crazy for hours!

Comment: should be fixed with https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/0c387deb21263aff6bc4864618e3cb74dcf32357

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\end{frame}` *must* start at the beginning of the line. You have

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]

        Hello World

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

use

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

        Hello World

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: good catch I'll adjust the formatting in the question to put that back (+1)

Comment: Why do we need the \end{frame} to be at the beginning of the line ?

Comment: beamer must collect the contents of a frame before it will be typeset.  And the end of the contents is reached if the current line is `\end{frame}`, without additional characters before and after

Comment: What a disarming answer... So, is this beamers' fault?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis: It's no fault, it is the syntax of the environment

Comment: Let's call it in another way than "fault", but it's surely not a "happy thing". I mean, it forces one to ruin a nice indentation.