# How to prevent parts of source from being automatically indented?

Tags: beamer, listings, texstudio, editors

**EDIT** Rephrased question to be more abstract and less specific to only `fragile`-frames.

Context:

While recompiling a presentation, the process halted with err-msg

`file ended while scanning use of next`.

During debugging the whole thing I found indented `fragile`-frames, although they weren't supposed to be.

I assume, TeXstudio might have indented the code as part of the code folding routine.

---

> **Problem:**
>   How do I prevent parts of source code from being automatically indented? How can `arara` or `latexindent` be utilized for this purpose?

A minimalistic WE using `fragile`-frame to exemplify the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

%not to be indented by texstudio!
\begin{frame}[fragile]{a title}
some explanation to the snippet
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=func foo not bar,label=fct:foo]
foo(a,b,c)
    c = a + b
    return c
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

%allowed to be indented.
   \begin{frame}{smart title}
   some input
   \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to (La)TeX in the sense that it is probably a design consideration for the TeXstudio development team. Moreover, this seems a super-specific request: A `frame` that is `fragile` under `beamer` containing a `lstlisting`. What if you define a `lstnewenvironment`, or it's not in `beamer`, or...?

Comment: @Werner: according to help center, it is a question about TeX related tools (4th bullet). Yes, the problem itself might be very specfic in this case, the behaviour is not limited to only fragile-frames. The solution could be adapted to other sections of code, which aren't allowed to be indented as well. I'm currently rephrasing the question. Not sure how this would make it more on-topic, though.

Comment: @Naphaneal Yes, but the point that this can only be solved in the editor remains. Feature requests for editors are off-topic as they can only be implemented by the developers.

Comment: @Naphaneal Another approach would be to allow indented `\end{frame}`s http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234778/indenting-endframe-in-fragile-slides