# Cannot use verbatim in latex beamer (despite using [fragile] and no indentations/comments)

Tags: beamer, verbatim

Minimum Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]  

\begin{verbatim} 
asd
\end{verbatim}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Error: "File ended while scanning use of \next."

Unfortunately this didn't fix it:
[Beamer - ! File ended while scanning use of \next](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225581/beamer-file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-next)

Comment: Probably you have installed to old version of `beamer`. With recent version (3.61 ) it works without any problem.

Comment: As Zarko mentions, you can add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` (perhaps outcomment the `verbatim` part), then a compilation lists the package/class versions you are using. Additionally, just the generated `.log` for this example from your sise, would also be of interest for those trying to help. As it can sometimes show MikTeX installations that are not properly updated.

Comment: @Zarko: Sorry this is maybe a stupid question, but how can I update beamer? I think I never installed it actually, I thought it comes automatically when using it like any (other) package.

Comment: Depends on your LaTeX installation. For example, if you use MikTeX, than find MikTeX Console and in it click on "Check for Updates". After while, when Console will find all packages needed to be updated, klick on button "Update" and then in new window on "Update now".